# Format String from TextBox to TimeValue in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a TextBox in a UserForm. using the event _AfterUpdate(), I want to update the format to TimeValue, "hh:mm" using this code.

```
Private Sub TimeTextBox_AfterUpdate()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

With TimeTextBox
    .Value = Format(TimeValue(.Value), "hh:mm")
ErrorHandler:
    .Value = Format(TimeValue(Now), "hh:mm")
End With

End Sub
```

The problem: it will always fail, even if I enter 13:13 in the box. How do I solve this?

Comment: This will create a loop. After your textbox updates, you are updating it again which will cause afterupdate to fire again.  When you say it will fail, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @MatthewD commented, you're creating an infinite loop by updating the textbox inside the update event. Eventually VBA quits looping, so it's not quite infinite. You keep getting the current time because you don't `Exit Sub` prior to your `ErrorHandler:`. The code under your error handling label gets executed 100% of the time.

If you put `Exit Sub` on the line above `ErrorHandler:` then the code below will only get executed if there's an error.

However, I'll propose a different way.

```
Private mbEventsDisabled As Boolean

Private Sub TimeTextBox_AfterUpdate()

    Dim dtTime As Date

    'See if you can convert the text into a time
    On Error Resume Next
        dtTime = TimeValue(Me.TimeTextBox.Value)
    On Error GoTo 0

    'if you can't, the variable will be zero and you set
    'it to the current time
    If dtTime = 0 Then dtTime = Now

    'To prevent recursive calling, see if you've disabled events
    If Not mbEventsDisabled Then

        'disable events so you can update the textbox
        mbEventsDisabled = True

        'now this line will trigger AfterUpdate again, but it won't
        'execute this if block because of the variable
        Me.TimeTextBox.Value = Format(dtTime, "hh:mm")

        'now re-enable events
        mbEventsDisabled = False
    End If

End Sub
```

You can't disable events in a userform with `Application.EnableEvents`, so you have to do it yourself. I create a module level variable called `mbEventsDisabled` that will keep track of whether events are enabled (Module level variables are declared in the declarations section of the module, outside of and above any procedures). It's best to name this variable in the negative because a Boolean variable will be False by default and you want disabled=false unless you set it otherwise.

Instead of updating the textbox in the main code and in an error handler, I just only update it in one spot. It makes the code cleaner I think.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect, just what I wanted. There was only one problem and that was that I did not know I had to declare mbEventsDisabled at the top of all the code (saying this in case another beginner have the same problem).